Chrome Android escala tamaño del texto según el número de párrafos del mismo
Tengo un problema con Chrome Android y es que escala muchísimo el tamaño del texto según las líneas que ocupe el párrafo sin respetar el tamaño de letra indicado (px, em, rem, %, etc.). Solo pasa con Chrome android y navegadores basados en él, en la versión de escritorio de Chrome y en el resto de navegadores el tamaño de letra se mantiene o escala muy poco. Ejemplo


<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body style="background-color:black;">
  <div id="global2" style="margin:0px auto; width:1000px; background-color:white;">
    <div id="cuerpo2">
      <div style="width:1000px; float:left; font-size:50px; color:white;">
        <p id="" style="float:left; margin-top:30px; text-align:center; width:1000px;">
            Esta es una prueba de que el número de filas del texto escala el tamaño de todo el párrafo en google chrome android pero no en otros navegadores ni en la versión de PC.
        </p>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>



Sí en el ejemplo anterior el texto no pasara por ancho a otra línea si que respetaría el tamaño de letra indicado pero el problema sucede cuando se supera. En el resto de navegadores no Chrome Android escala muy poco el tamaño de letra indicado independientemente de las líneas del párrafo.
Gracias por la ayuda
Edito: añado captura de pantalla para mayor claridad. el problema ocurre si se salta a la tercera línea:


Una captura de pantalla mostrando el problema vendría de perillas.

mira este post donde podras ver a detalles cuales son las unidades relativas para texto y para contenedores https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units

El post está muy bien para explicar las unidades absolutas y relativas pero ya había probado a hacerlo con ambas y es lo mismo, escala a partir del segundo párrafo como en el ejemplo, es como si fuera algo relacionado con la accesibilidad de chrome Android :-(

¿hay alguna forma de deshabilitar la accesibilidad por defecto de los navegadores desde php?
